# change path of screenshot taken by calabash in ios simulator on scenario failure using ruby

Tags: ios, ruby, screenshot, calabash, calabash-ios

i am using calabash to do testing on a iOS native app. calabash takes a screenshot and names it screenshot_0 on scenario failure and saves it in my project directory.
i want to know how i can change the path of the screenshot and how i can change the name of the file.

i used the following:

```
dir_path = "/Users/bmw/Desktop/Calabash/screenshots "
unless Dir.exist?(dir_path)
    Dir.mkdir(dir_path,0777)
    puts "=========Directory is created at #{dir_path}"
else
    puts "=========Directory already exists at #{dir_path}"
end

#Run after each scenario
After do |scenario|
  #Check, scenario is failed?
  if(scenario.failed?)
         time = Time.now.strftime('%Y_%m_%d_%Y_%H_%M_%S_')
         name_of_scenario = time + scenario.name.gsub(/\s+/, "_").gsub("/","_")
         puts "Name of snapshot is #{name_of_scenario}"
         file_path = File.expand_path(dir_path)+'/'+name_of_scenario +'.png'
         page.driver.simulator.save_screenshot file_path
         puts "Snapshot is taken"
    puts "#===========================================================#"
    puts "Scenario:: #{scenario.name}"
    puts "#===========================================================#"
  end
end
```

i had seen page.driver.browser,simulator.save_screenshot somewhere... and replaced browser with simulator and that did not work...
is there any way to change location where ios sim saves simulator without touching failure_helpers?

Comment: i replaced page.driver.simulator.save_screenshot file_path to screenshot file_path and got the error message: no implicit conversion of Symbol into integer (typeError)

Comment: I'm not sure about the error, but it's probably due having passed unexpected parameters to the `screenshot` method, see my answer for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calabash exposes and [environment variable named `SCREENSHOT_PATH`](http://calabashapi.xamarin.com/ios/file.ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLES.html#SCREENSHOT_PATH) you can use to set the path where to save the screenshots.

As for the file name, you might want to try and use the `screenshot` API. Reading your comment you seem to have tried it already, but I think you might not have used the proper signature.

Looking at the [source for `screenshot`](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/blob/b419a095dd4e23beb162bd5cfb4c1b641adb0306/calabash-cucumber/lib/calabash-cucumber/failure_helpers.rb#L19) we see that it's defined like this:

```
def screenshot(options={:prefix => nil, :name => nil})
  ...
```

As you can see it's expecting a map, so what you should try is

```
screenshot({:name => name_of_scenario })
```

Also note that the documentation says that the use of [`screenshot_embed`](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/blob/b419a095dd4e23beb162bd5cfb4c1b641adb0306/calabash-cucumber/lib/calabash-cucumber/failure_helpers.rb#L51) is preferred to `screenshot`.

Comment: ah. i did that( screenshot({:name => name_of_scenario }) ) and i still did not get the screenshot in the right place. will try screenshot_embed and try that today. thank you.